# Can I get a return for listbox with 0 items

Tags: c#

I want to receive a particular listbox item, but some of listboxes have 0 items in them. If I ever get that particular listbox with 0 items, I therefore return a null value.

My Code for getting the item with 0 items:

```
Listbox1.Items[0].ToString().NullIfZero());
```

My Code for trying to return the item(with empty items) into a null value

```
public static string NullifZero(this string a)
{
    return ListBox.Items.Count==0 (a) ? "" : a;           <--- ERROR
}
```

The return code is obviously wrong, but I want it to return if a particular listbox has no item.

Comment: What does the 'ERROR' say sir?

Comment: You are doing the check at the wrong position. A `string` does not have any Items. What `ListBox` are you even accessing there? Do the check on the list box, not on the `ToString()` result of the first entry.

Comment: I'm trying to check multiple listboxes, the reason why I'm trying to see if the listbox items count are 0. I want to know if the various listbox items would have 0 items, and if they do have 0 items, it would result into a null value or a " "

Comment: I understand what you are trying. It is still at the wrong position. Do something like `if(Listbox1.Items.Count == 0) return null; else return ListBox1.Items.First().ToString()`. Alternatively, you can use the more compact (but harder to understand) statement `return Listbox1.Items.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()`. Btw, an empty string is not `null`.

Comment: We know why you're trying to check the `ListBox` but your code has already called `ToiString` on the first item in the `ListBox` before it does that check, so it's too late then. You need to do the check BEFORE you get an item.

Comment: Ohhh okay, I understand now. But, if I have, let's say 9 listboxes I want to check, is there any way to make it moreso that I don't have to check each one individually?

Comment: Add some more context and we will be able to help you. You can put every logic you like in a function and call that function 9 times for your 9 list boxes.

Comment: I'm trying to add the parameter from a listbox item using 
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select Volume from [Inventory Table] where Description='" + Listbox1.Items[0].ToString().NullIfZero()); + "'", Con); and I'm doing this for 9 listboxes, If it has no item or the item count is 0, I want it to get a NULL value instead.